# iOS accessibility - How to localize VoiceOver language

Tags: ios, accessibility

My app is in the process of becoming localized for a few languages and regions.  How Do I localize the voiceOver (its a accessbility feature for the blind).  I want the language of voiceOver and voiceControl to change based on the users selected language ?

in my info plist the Localization native development region (CFBundleDevelopmentRegion) is already set to en_us as a fail safe if no language is found to localize to.

So to make it clear, i want to know if i localize all my strings in the app will the voiceOver use the localization in my app ?

Answer (score 2):

In `viewDidLoad`

```
    changeNationButton.accessibilityLabel = NSLocalizedString ("Change Nation", comment: "Accessibility Label: Button to change Nation")
    changeNationButton.accessibilityHint = NSLocalizedString ("Tap to Change Nation", comment: "Accessibility Hint: Button to change Nation")
```

then localize it as a normal String in localizable.strings

```
"Change Nation" = "Cambia Nazione";
```